# Close modeless dialog when another window closes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have a modeless dialog which I'm creating as below,

```
CPlotDlg * newd = new CPlotDlg ();
newd->Create(IDD_PLOT,this->GetParentOwner());
newd->SetParent(this->GetParentFrame()->GetParent());
newd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

I want to close this dialog when a different window closes (not the parent). How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just, save CPlotDlg* to other window which will be used for closing CPlotDlg window.

If the closer window is SomeWhereDlg,

```
class SomeWhereDlg
{
  public:
  ...
  ...
  CPlotDlg* m_plotDlg;
};

void SomeWhereDlg::SetPlotDlg(CPlotDlg* plotDlg)
{
  ASSERT(plotDlg);
  if(plotDlg == nullptr) { return;}

  m_plotDlg = plotDlg;
}
```

And then, when create CPlotDlg window, save the pointer.

```
CPlotDlg* newd = new CPlotDlg ();       
//Save newd(CPlotDlg*) to somewhere
//i.e) specific window which will close this newd window
//SomeWhereDlg->SetPlotDlg(newd);

newd->Create(IDD_DIALOG1,this->GetParentOwner());
newd->SetParent(this);
newd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

if a closing event occur, just call Close() or delete, etc via m_plotDlg.

Comment: The problem is I can't create an instance of SomeWhereDlg, as it's already created in a different class.

Comment: I think your situation is below,
1)SomewhereDlg cannot be created once more.
2)SomewhereDlg have to close CPlotDlg window in relevant time.

as above rules,
you have to save SomeWhereDlg instance pointer to global variable or in any accessible window class.

Answer (score 0):

To close the modeless dialog save the pointer as CodeDreamer shows, and call m_plotDlg->DestroyWindow()

Comment: Or, post WM_CLOSE to the window.